# AngularJS - Ng-change updating value but not toggling radio button

Tags: angularjs

I have two input options that are linked via ng-model in order to display always the same country in both places.

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in countries">
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in countries">
```

Each country has different shipping costs, and once the country is selected you can also choose between different shipping options ("normal" and "express" with a radio button. I want to make it always display the "normal" cost when switching the country, and I made it by adding a ng-click to each of the input options and adding a ng-change in order to listen to the changes:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-change="changeShipping()" ng-click="shippingPrice=selectedCountry.shipping.normal">
```

The problem is that while the data shown in the view is the correct when changing the country, but the radio button is still set in the wrong option.
This is my controller logic:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.countries = [{
    "name": "Freedonia",
    "shipping" : 
    {
      "normal":30,
      "express":70
    }
  },{
    "name": "Mordor",
    "shipping" : 
    {
      "normal":70,
      "express":110
    }
  },{
    "name": "Oz",
    "shipping" : 
    {
      "normal":140,
      "express":180
    }
  }];

  $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[0];

$scope.changeShipping = function() {    
  return $scope.shippingPrice = $scope.selectedCountry.shipping.normal;
};
});
```

You can see a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zrnsvytd/) Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the fiddle? It's this one :) http://jsfiddle.net/zrnsvytd/

Comment: Yeah, I've removed my comment when you updated your question with link to the jsfiddle.

Comment: No problem! It seems we were out of synch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-model with [input[radio]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) and set it's value on select change.

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lqf4oxj/1/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shippingType = 'normal'; // initial value for input[radio]

    $scope.countries = [{
        "name": "Freedonia",
        "shipping": {
            "normal": 30,
            "express": 70
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Mordor",
        "shipping": {
            "normal": 70,
            "express": 110
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Oz",
        "shipping": {
            "normal": 140,
            "express": 180
        }
    }];

    $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[0];

    $scope.changeShipping = function () {
        $scope.shippingType = 'normal';    // set back to normal on country change
        return $scope.shippingPrice = $scope.selectedCountry.shipping.normal;
    };
});
```

```css
.summary{
  background-color:gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  font-family:Arial;
  margin-bottom:52px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="summary">
  Summary:<br>
  Country:<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-change="changeShipping()">
    </select><br>
  Shipping Costs: 
    {{selectedCountry.shipping[shippingType]}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-change="changeShipping()">
    </select>
  </div>
  
  Shipping costs:
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="shippingOptions" value="normal" ng-model="shippingType">
    Normal {{selectedCountry.shipping.normal}}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="shippingOptions" value="express" ng-model="shippingType">
    Express {{selectedCountry.shipping.express}}<br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That's indeed a much cleaner solution. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @Joe82 one more tip: your `changeShipping` function could not return a value, because it doesn't make sense. Also I like that you use `ng-change` instead of watching the scope, it's much better, even though people usually pick `$watch` instead.

Comment: Yep, thanks I see your correction. I have been reading about ng-change lately and it solves a lot of problems that $watch was giving to me (I recommend this article to anybody new to it http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/11/using-ng-change-instead-of-$watch-in-angular/)