# Angular JS - Error with http request with nested scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question is based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061899/angularjs-ng-change-updating-value-but-not-toggling-radio-button/38062164#38062164) previous answer.

I am trying to send an http request where one of the elements I want to send is expressed in the view as

```
{{selectedCountry.shipping[shippingType]}}
```

The request has to go along other element so in order to make a single request I mix them together with

```
$scope.checkoutData = angular.extend($scope.selectedCountry.shipping[$scope.shippingType], $scope.selectedCountry.name);
```

And then send the request with

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http.post('process.php', $scope.checkoutData)
};
```

But when doing the second step I get an error. You can see [the working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1y61pxeh/) (with the second step commented, so it doesn't break the code). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject $http to your controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 ...
})
```

The error i see in your plunker is :

```
ReferenceError: $http is not defined
```

For your second issue with angular.extend, try changing your submit function to:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    var checkoutData = {
        shippingAmount: $scope.selectedCountry.shipping[$scope.shippingType],
        country: $scope.selectedCountry.name
     }

    $http.post('process.php', checkoutData)
};
```

Comment: That was missing, I have just fixed it :). But still then when I uncomment the expression it still gives an error http://jsfiddle.net/v3o87L5z/

Comment: it seems like $scope.selectedCountry.shipping[$scope.shippingType] evalutes to a number which is 30. you cannot extend numbers only objects...